# Merge hash with array of hashes based on value in shared key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I start with the following:

```
@prod = []
@num = []
@todd = [{:sellersku=>"2273500028", :num=>"B0076E32F8", :price=>"15.49"}, 
{:sellersku=>"5154464774", :num=>"B00013J6HY", :price=>"445.94"}]
```

Then create a lookup array:

```
@todd.each do |x|  
  @num << x[:num]
end
```

Then using the lookup array go thru an API that loads various data into results:

```
@num.each do |x|
call_api(x) #I left out the code that populates the variables below..
results = {:num => x,  
:vendor => vendor, :type => type, :color => @color, :image => hi_image
}
end
```

When the above finishes calling the api, I want to merge the @todd array and the results array into the @prod array of hashes. Resulting in this.

```
[{:sellersku=>"2273500028", :num=>"B0076E32F8", :price=>"15.49",
:vendor => "Boss", :type => "Shoes", :color => "Blue", :image => boss.jpg}, 
{:sellersku=>"5154464774", :num=>"B00013J6HY", :price=>"34.49",
:vendor => "Converse", :type => "Shirt", :color => "Orange", 
:image => cons.jpg}]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do... why not simply populate the existing @todd hash (or a duplicate) with the info: `@prod = @todd.map {|h| h.merge(call_api h[:num] ) }` ... assuming `call_api` returns a hush with the values in place. What is the difference you are trying to achieve?

Comment: So the issue I'm having is sending the num through to call the api, and then when the results hash gets populated merging the @todd hash so that num matches on each and the correct price is merged with the correct num.. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
@prod = []
@num = []
@todd = [
  {:sellersku=>"2273500028", :num=>"B0076E32F8", :price=>"15.49"},
  {:sellersku=>"5154464774", :num=>"B00013J6HY", :price=>"445.94"}
]

@todd.each do |hash|
  serial_number = hash[:num]

  # EXTERNAL CALL TO API
  info = api_call(serial_number) #likely returns json
  # parse into new hash called results

  results = {
    :vendor => vendor,
    :type => type,
    :color => @color,
    :image => hi_image
  }

  @prod << hash.merge(results)
end

@prod
# after iteration, @prod will have all the information you are looking for.
```